# How many enemies can I tag?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

When you use your focus, enemies are highlighted in colour, and you can press `R2` to tag them, which places an arrow over their head.

So far I've tagged up quite a few, but is there a maximum amount of tags I can have active at any one time?

Comment: I have not encountered such a maximum.  I was, for example, able to tag every enemy inside one of the larger Bandit Camps.  I think the limit to the number of tags is probably equal to the limit of taggable entities that the game can render on the screen at once.  (Which may be why tags are auto-removed once you get beyond Focus range away from them.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As dg99 pointed out, and from my own experience as well, there does not seem to be a limit to how many enemies you can tag at once. It would seem that it is only limited by the render distance of the game; sometimes human enemies glow a faint orange to signify their distance away, and occasionally I cannot tag them. **Otherwise, you can tag all enemies that are within range of your Focus.**